# How to animate a div using css3

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have following code:

```js
$('.div-1').on('click', function() {
  $('.block').addClass('animated');
});
$('.div-2').on('click', function() {
  $('.block2').addClass('animated');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.div-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  background: tomato;
}
.div-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  background: tan;
}
.block2 {
  background: green;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation: animateThis 0.2s ease;
  animation: animateThis 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.block {
  background: red;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateThis {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
keyframes animateThis {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>

<section class="block"></section>
<section class="block2"></section>
```

Here is a ***[PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjaRdg)***

What I am trying to do: when clicking on `div-1` or `div-2` the corresponding animation for sections `block` and `block2` should originate from the the **bottom center** of `div-1` or `div-2`. It currently starts animating from the **left corner**.

My question is: how do I get the animation to originate from the **bottom center** of `div-1` or `div-2` and not the **left corner**. Also, when clicking on `div-1` or `div-2` the currently open section should close (with the reverse animation of how it is opened) and the corresponding clicked `div` should open as a fresh animation. How can this be done through scripting? I do not want to use external libraries (animate.css). I have tried several approaches to this but I have no idea how to do it as I cannot work out the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a separate animation to hide the blocks

```
 @-webkit-keyframes shrinkThis {
      0% {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

And you can use a call back to know that the block is hidden and then expand the corresponding block

```
$(".block").bind("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", 
  function() {
      $('.block2').removeClass('shrink');
      $('.block2').addClass('expand');
      $('.block2').unbind();
  });
```

Here is the [PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waBXVO)

**Edit for positioning:**
You can use *transform-origin* as pointed out by someone. But it will work only with transforms like scale, translate etc.

The block's css should be something like following:

```
.block {
  /*background: red;*/
  position:absolute;
  border:solid 1px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  transform-origin: 20px 0%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 20px 0%;
}
```

The transform is using scale instead of modifying height and width:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateThis {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1,0.1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}
```

Here is the updated **[PEN](http://codepen.io/clickdilip/pen/eNmjrR)**

Area to improve: The transform origin should be calculated dynamically.

Comment: animation rollback is working properly, but i need to focus on the position where it loads the animation.

Comment: @Shanaka I've updated the answer for position of animation load

Comment: Yes good job ! Just a little remark on here : -webkit- are also used by chrome. And you don't have to put -webkit-xxx transforms in the @keyframes clauses, and same for @-webkit-keyframes with transform lines. It will not be used.

Comment: @Alex- Good to know. Thanks. I've updated my answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Alex and Dilip thank you with the answers been most helpful and relevant to my troubled question.

Comment: Dilip mhh I meant to respond to browsers specification you should use the same syntax : in @-webkit-keyframes { -... -webkit-transform : ... } and in @keyframes { ... transform : ....} . that's all :)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to play around with the starting point of your animation like you asked, you can use transform-origin CSS property.
Write

```
transform-origin: 50% 100%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
```

to make it start from the bottom center.

And to use the reversed animation, just add the keyword **alternate** after your animation directives. It will play the animation reverted after being completed.

Exampe :

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation: animateThis 0.2s ease alternate;
  animation: animateThis 0.2s ease alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: im not familiar on how to use the following, could you kindly provide with an fiddle would be most helpful.

Comment: i did a little bit of searching can "transform-origin" be used with css3 keyframe animations?

Comment: of course you can ! ill provide you a fiddle when i'll have 5 min to help you understand how it works.

Comment: i'm back with a little example made on cssdesk : http://cssdeck.com/labs/myo0lzi1
      the animation of smooth backward will not work here, but by using a transform scale and a transform-origin you will surely be able to make the axis on the center bottom.

Comment: the animation is working properly i can follow up from there to alter the toggle class, this is helpful to continue.